# How to install R on HP-UX environment

Tags: r, installation, hp-ux

I need to install `R packages` on `HP-UX`.

Please share the steps & the prerequisites.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any searching?3

Comment: https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/Install-R-on-HP-UX-ia64/td-p/4817511

Comment: Hi, yes I did a lot of searching about this request. I'd like to confirm if I only need the GNU GCC and MAKE to compile and install R on HP-UX. If anyone could help, I really appreciate.